# Why does the Xcode debugger show an object as (null) when it's clear the object has a non-null value?

Tags: xcode, lldb

In the debugger, we're printing an object and seeing this:

`po myInstance` ---> `Module.MyClassName (null)`

We can print properties of the object:

`po myInstance.id ---> 1234567`

Adding the object to an array increases the array count by 1.

We tried overriding the `description` property:

`override description: String { return "Foo" }`, and that now prints `Foo` in the debugger on `po`.

Are we missing something simple? Why would we have to explicitly override `description`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I try what you've said, I get `<MyClassName: 0x600002128070>` in the console. Could you give more detail for reproducing?

Comment: @matt `MyClassName` is a subclass of an internal base class I can't share, unfortunately. The base class of _that_ class is `NSObject`. Also, if it makes a difference, `MyClassName` is a Swift class being used in Objective-C. Is there anything else I can give you?

Comment: All of that could have been relevant, so you certainly should have included it in the question. — However, I still can't reproduce. I pause in the Objective-C code which uses MyClassName from Swift, and I get `<MyModule.MyClassName: 0x600003804140>`. The fact that you don't get any statement of this object's address is extremely odd and I can't account for it.

Comment: That doesn't look to me like the normal description printing that you would get from a swift object.  Are you sure you don't have another description method somewhere in this class hierarchy that is producing this message?